# Как создать ярлык в Windows для запуска команды adb?

Tags: android, cmd, adb, android-adb

Требуется найти простой способ запуска команды `adb`. Хотелось бы через, например, ярлык на рабочем столе. В данный момент я запускаю `adb` и набираю там команду

> adb connect 192.168.43.1

Это долго и неудобно. Однажды у меня получалось запускать команду `netsh` для создания точки доступа через ярлык, но вот с `adb` я пробовал и у меня не получилось.

Также буду рад и другим способам быстрого запуска помянутой команды.

Comment: .bat ; .cmd файлик можешь написать, туда можно вбить консольные команды

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте bat файл на рабочем столе с содержимым:

> adb connect 192.168.43.1

согласно документации так работает. Возможно надо будет еще указать параметр -Н
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#howadbworks